# Ember Select to Update Model onChange

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember HBS template form with input and select fields. Input fields use a 'value' argument set to model.someField. When a user changes the input value, the model also gets changed and then shows there are changedAttributes staged.

I want to do this exact same thing with a select, but when I change the select value, the model.someField isnt getting updated automatically. What's the right way to do this?

I'm using Ember 2.9.

Comment: You need to set the selected value to `model.someField` upon onselect event. definitely, we need code you attempted to give more direction. for dropdown you may consider [ember-power-select addon](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select). it's very powerful addon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to kumkanillam for this answer.

Adding onchange={{action (mut value) value="target.value"}} to the select fixed the auto update on the model.

Comment: Update per year 2022. This raises test error, since "action" is disambiguation. It is suggested to pass the action instead, e.g. `onChange={{doMyAction}}`

Comment: Furthermore, it is going to be deprecated. See https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/action-on-and-fn/